# Angular 2 model into a function

Tags: angular

I pull data from my firebase database.

This is my service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { RealEstatePhotography } from './real-estate-photography';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RealEstatePhotographyService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private http: Http) { }

private realEstate =  this.af.database.list('realestate');

  getItems(){
    return (this.realEstate);
  }


  getItem(title: RealEstatePhotography) : Observable<any>{
    return this.realEstate
    .map((list: Array<any>) => {
      let result: RealEstatePhotography = new RealEstatePhotography();
      if (list){
        list.forEach(element => {
          if (element.title === title){
            result = element
          }
        });
        return result;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this is my detail component:

```js
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RealEstatePhotography } from '../real-estate-photography';
import { RealEstatePhotographyService } from '../real-estate-photography.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-real-estate-photography-detail',
  templateUrl: './real-estate-photography-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./real-estate-photography-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [RealEstatePhotographyService],
})
export class RealEstatePhotographyDetailComponent implements OnInit {

photos = this.photo();
realEstate;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _realEstatePhotographyService: RealEstatePhotographyService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  photo(){
    var location = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++){
      Array(i);
    }
    return console.log(Array(i));

  }


  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let title = params['title'];
      let realEstate = this._realEstatePhotographyService.getItem(title).subscribe(realEstate => {
        this.realEstate = realEstate

      });
    });
  }
}
```

this is my html from that component.

```html
<p>{{realEstate.folder}}</p>
```

This is the data I get:

[image]

Now, my question is. I need to put that result into the "location" variable i have in the photo() function.

something like var location = this.realEstate.folder or {{realEstate.folder}}

I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you

here is a plunk but, of course, does not return into anything because i am not connected to firebase

https://plnkr.co/edit/a0WKevpXpwvY8x7NG1cb?p=preview

Comment: Would you like to provide plunker?

Comment: I don't understand the issue: " I need to put that result into the 'location' variable". Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Per, I know is a bit confusing. It has been really hard to explain. 
do you see the result I get in the page? Well, I need to put that data into the location
something like: var location = ""https://s3.amazonaws.com/gadaphotos/photos/portfolio/alden_park/" 
but get that data from my firebase. I just put the {{realEstate.folder}} and I get that data. I want to put something similar like: var location = {{realEstate.folder}} in order to get the same data. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand, why not just pass the `realEstate.folder` to the `photo`-function from within your subscription: `this.photo(realEstate.folder)´`and then `photo(val) { var location = val }`?

Comment: Like this: https://embed.plnkr.co/ZWjqb1kWbKR2ZiNWNlBV/

Comment: Thank you Unitario. I tried that but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to do, but perhaps this might get you closer?

Note that this.location will be 'undefined' until your observable returns data. If you are using this in the template you can use *ngIf="location" on the tag.

```
    export class RealEstatePhotographyDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    photos = this.photo();
    realEstate;
    private location: any;

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _realEstatePhotographyService: RealEstatePhotographyService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

      photo(){

if(this.location) {


        for (var i = 0; i < this.location.length; i++){
          Array(i);
        }
        return console.log(Array(i));
    }
      }


      ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          let title = params['title'];
          let realEstate = this._realEstatePhotographyService.getItem(title).subscribe(realEstate => {
            this.realEstate = realEstate
    this.location=realEstate.folder;
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, per. It does not work. I am looking for another alternatives. I did element Reference and I can finally get the data but still, it does not do what I need.
Thank you for your help